# Problems with Tooltip Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, tooltip, visual-studio-2019

Somehow, when I try to use the Debug function of C# in Visual studios for a Unity project, my Visual studios doesn't show the tooltip with the correct option. Instead, it shows a function from other library that won't work for me in these case. I'm worried I might have this problem with other functions and methods, like, even though I write the Debug without the help of tooltip, when I try to use Debug.Log, the option in tooltip isn't the one I've been looking for.

In case you wounder about my code, it's the simple one you get when you create a C# file through Unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class Player : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        private void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log("Hello");
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {
            Debug.Log("Goodbye");
        }
    }
```

Just for illustration, here's an image of the problem. It show the function Debug from "System.diagnostics.Debug", but I wanted it to come from "System.Collections".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb8Qq.jpg)

Comment: I've tried to use some oders functions and methods like "transform" and the tooltip doesn't work well either. I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You must install Unity SDK Tool in VisualStudio installer [image: SeeThis]